# twitter bootstrap clearfix push down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, push, clearfix

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3, to design a layout, which has two columns, a float sidebar and a main content with a left margin relative to the sidebar size, but when I use the clearfix class in an ***ul*** element inside the main content, seems that the **clearfix** class, clean the sidebar(float clear) and push the ***ul*** and subsequent content down.

see http://bootply.com/97603

HTML

```
<aside id="sidebar">
<h1>Search Items</h1>
<form id="searchForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">Category 1</option>
            <option value="2">Category 2</option>
            <option value="3">Category 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="term">Search Term</label>
        <input type="text" name="term" id="term" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background: #F7F5FA;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container-full {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    display: block
}
#sidebar #searchForm{
    padding: 10px;
}
#main-content{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 260px;
    background: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: auto;
}
.gallery ul{
    background: black;
}
.gallery li{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.gallery li a{
    display: block;
}
```

How can i fix this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this class to your CSS:

```
.row{
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://bootply.com/97617)

---

it is because of your `aside`, you set fixed width to `aside` and set margin to your `main-content`, this is not right way to put element side by side. but if you use percentage width to your `aside` and `main-content` and use `float` it will look good and there is no need for `overflow:hidden` (or auto).

look at this:

[**DEMO**](http://bootply.com/97993)

```
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;   /*  instead 260px */
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    display: block
}

#main-content{
    background: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 80%;   /*  instead auto   */
    float:left;   /*  added          */
}
```

Comment: This works, but I can't understand why, so can you explain this behavior?. Note: I have seen that .row{ overflow: auto; } works too.

Answer (score 1):

```
#main-content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
margin: 0 0 0 260px;
min-height: 600px;
position: relative;
width: auto;
```

}

change position:relative to position:absolute in above id your problem will be solved..